# Add Respring Button in setting.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, tweak

do you know how can I add a Respring button in Setting>My tweak?

I know the code must added in the PreferenceBundle folder, but I don't know the code :D

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKmuK.jpg

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I know how to use Theos (if this can be useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For theos just do this:

1. In the settings bundle open "resources" and then the .plist file of your tweak (maybe it will be "my tweak settings.plist" and add a button with this value:

   `cell: PSButtonCell
    label: Respring
    action: respring`
2. Now go back in your settings bundle and open the file called "my tweak settings.mm" and, in the @implementation part, add the method for the respiring action:

```cpp
     -(void)respring {

         [(SpringBoard *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] _relaunchSpringBoardNow];

      }
```

Non you will have a PSButtonCell that will respiring your device.

Comment: Really thanks! But now I have the button but if I click on it nothing happens. This is my .mm: https://ghostbin.com/paste/948q4 and this is my .plsit: https://ghostbin.com/paste/e27r2 Btw are you italian? :)

Comment: So remake the part of the respiring button in the .plist file in the correct order: `cell - label - action` and show me you "makefile" file. However, yes I'm italian ;)

Comment: Really thanks! Now work so good! But not the tweak :( If you want help me on it add me on Skype: sup3rgiu. I'm italian too

Comment: Just give me you source code if you want and mark my answer as correct please

Comment: https://github.com/sup3rgiu/ColorFlash The tweak appear in setting.app and I can change the selector, but nothing happens. I tried to do a respring too, but nothing :(

Comment: @SUPERGIU I've correct your tweak here https://github.com/perascotta/ColorFlash ;) I think that now it will works perfectly!! Just a note: when you hook a `(void)` function, just remember that "(void)" is equal to "nothing to return".

Comment: OMG THANKS!!! Now works sooo goood! :) Btw do you know if is possible add this: http://www.3dmax-tutorials.com/graphics/il_hsv_sliders.jpg or how to use this: https://github.com/InfinitApps/InfColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

I know Codyd51 has some good examples of tweaks.

Look at his Github to get read up on PreferenceBundles.

https://github.com/codyd51/Theos-Examples

I know, they can be confusing! :D

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .mm file in you preference bundle folder:

```
-(void)respring {
  system("killall -9 Springboard");
}
```

In your .plist (preference_folder/resources/)add above the :

```
 <dict>
      <key>action</key>
      <string>respring</string>
      <key>cell</key>
      <string>PSButtonCell</string>
      <key>label</key>
      <string>Respring your        device</string>
   </dict>
```